# CountDownLatch in HandlerThread locking on await in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, firebase

I'm trying to synchronize my Android device's SMS messages with a Firebase DB. What I have done so far:

- Created an Android service that gets started at the boot intent
- Added a content observer that triggers the onStartCommand
- Implemented the Firebase code to authenticate & write my SMS messages

So far, so good, all seems to work pretty well. **Except** that it looks like the onStartCommand is not very happy with Firebase's asynchronous calls and quits the execution of it all somewhere in the middle (e.g. not all selected messages have been synced).

I want to prevent the thread to 'exit' (or get killed, or whatever reason why this behaviour occurs) only when the full sync has been done ofcourse. For this I added 2 things already:

- The concept of using CountDownLatch and it's await function to hold code execution (wait) for the asynchronous calls to complete (as suggested on https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html, bottom section)
- Implemented the concept of HandlerThreads (as explained on http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to use a different thread for the message handling (which shouldn't have a problem being blocked, in contrast to the main thread).

My code for this is listed below, I tried to remove as much unnecessary / unrelated code as possible.

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
    //thread handling
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    //Others
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private Firebase firebase;

    //Handler that receives messages
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        private ContentResolver mContentResolver;

        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
            super(looper);
            this.mContentResolver = contentResolver;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            final int msgToStop = msg.arg1;

            final String userId = firebase.getAuth().getUid();

            //making sure this doesn't get defined in Firebase's callback, might pose a problem since that runs in a different thread as well I presume. => should be lower in the code to function properly though.
            final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);

            Query queryRef = firebase.child("sms").child(userId).orderByChild("_id").limitToLast(1);
            queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    int highestId = 0;
                    (...) -> get highest id from Firebase snapshot

                    Uri allMessages = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                    String[] selectionArgs = {Integer.valueOf(highestId).toString()};
                    mCursor = mContentResolver.query(SmsQuery.CONTENT_URI, SmsQuery.PROJECTION, SmsQuery.SELECTION, selectionArgs, SmsQuery.SORT_ORDER);

                    Firebase postRef = firebase.child("sms").child(userId);

                    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                                post1.put(mCursor.getColumnName(i), mCursor.getString(i));
                            }

                            postRef.child(post1.get("_id")).setValue(post1, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                                    done.countDown();
                                }
                            });
                            try {
                                done.await();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                (...)
                            }
                        } while (mCursor.moveToNext() && mCursor.getPosition() < 50);
                        mCursor.close();
                        stopSelf(msgToStop);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    (...)
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //initialize Firebase
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firebase = new Firebase("https://(firebaseURL).firebaseio.com");

        //Start up the tread running the service
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        //Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper,this.getContentResolver());

        //Register observer for new sms/mms messages
        this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/"), true, new SMSObserver(new Handler(),this.getApplicationContext()));

        //Try to authenticate Firebase
        firebaseAuthenticate();

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.close();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void firebaseAuthenticate(){
       (...)
    }

    private interface SmsQuery {
        (...)
    }

    public class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver {
        private Context context;
        private Handler handler;

        public SMSObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
            super(handler);
            this.context = context;
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri){
            Intent service = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
            context.startService(service);
            super.onChange(selfChange,uri);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens now is that the `done.await()` call seems to block everything even though the `done.countDown()` was processed ok.

Any ideas why? Any other remarks on the way of approaching this are welcome as well ofcourse. This is the first Android project I'm working on (even the last line of Java code I wrote was aaages ago) so I'm pretty new to all these concepts. It seems like handling asynchronous operations can be a PITA in Java?

Comment: `done.await()` will block the whole thread until `done.countDown()` is called. Could you further explain what your expected behavior is?

Comment: I was hoping that the `done.await()` would block just until the `done.countDown()` call in the completionlistener got triggered... if it doesn't do that, that can only mean both are actually running in the same thread?

On a higher level, I'd like to call `stopSelf` only when the onComplete callback finished for all messages...